# php contact form on wordpress site not running correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contacts

I am developing on XAMPP with a wordpress install.

My form looks good everything is how I want it but when I click the submit button it loads and index.php aka my websites home page.

so when I click submit it goes from

http://localhost/WP/contact/

to

http://localhost/WP/contact/index.php

It shouldn't work without any info in it though... I tried to follow a tutorial so I'm just lost and I'm still learning the basics of JS and PHP.

Here is my code for the form

```
<?php
                            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                                $name = $_POST['name'];
                                $email = $_POST['email'];
                                $message = $_POST['message'];
                                $from = 'From: $email'; 
                                $to = 'alexgray410@gmail.com'; 
                                $subject = 'Hello';

                                $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
                            }
                            ?>

                            <header class="body">

                            </header>

                            <section class="body">
                                <form method="post" action="index.php" class="contact">

                                    <label class="contact">Name</label>
                                    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here" class="contact">

                                    <label class="contact">Email</label>
                                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here" class="contact">

                                    <label class="contact">Message</label>
                                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here" class="contact"></textarea>
                                    <label class="contact">*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
                                    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here" class="contact">        
                                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="contact">

                                </form>
                            </section>

                        <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                            $name = $_POST['name'];
                            $email = $_POST['email'];
                            $message = $_POST['message'];
                            $from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
                            $to = 'demo@tangledindesign.com'; 
                            $subject = 'Hello';
                            $human = $_POST['human'];

                            $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

                            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                                if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
                                    if ($human == '4') {                 
                                        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                                        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                                    } else { 
                                        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                                    } 
                                } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                                    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
                                }
                                } else {
                                    echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
```

Comment: You aren't validating and returning false anywhere is what I understand by skimming through the code..

Comment: any way you can simplify or elaborate that for me, I'm not quite understanding

Answer (score 0):

you have not added headers, see the correct php mail format below.

```
$to=$to_email;
$subject ="Your subject";
$website="example.com";

// Set headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$website.'<'.$sender_email. ">\r\n";

// Format message
$contactMessage =
"Your message";
// Send email
$mail_sent=mail($to, $subject, $contactMessage, $headers);
```

Comment: is there any way you can simplify that for me? I'm a real newbie

Comment: in wordpress you can try contact 7 plugin for contact form

Comment: i like the custom look of this one. Shoud I try just editing the css of a form from cs7? 

I followed a tutorial exactly so I'm not sure where I went wrong, but if you coud help at all I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the website is in WordPress

at the end of `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){}` place header redirection of php

```
    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                            $name = $_POST['name'];
                            $email = $_POST['email'];
                            $message = $_POST['message'];
                            $from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
                            $to = 'demo@tangledindesign.com'; 
                            $subject = 'Hello';
                            $human = $_POST['human'];

                            $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

                            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                                if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
                                    if ($human == '4') {                 
                                        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                                        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                                    } else { 
                                        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                                    } 
                                } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                                    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
                                }
                                } else {
                                    echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
header("location:".get_the=permalink(<page_ID_of_CONTACT US page>));
                        ?>
    }
```

header() function should be last of everything but before closing the if condition

Comment: So I see where I would put it in the top if statement (before the start of the form), I think. 

But I'm confused as to where it would go in the more complicated if statement at the end of the code. Or do I only need to put it in one section at the end?

Comment: you need to put the header("location:".get_the=permalink(<page_ID_of_CONTACT US page>)) at the end of if condition .. just before } bracket

Comment: isn't there three if conditions? Does it need to go at the end of all of them, or only on the last one? Sorry I'm not grasping exactly what you mean

Comment: thanks bud, I'll give that a shot after I eat some breakfast. If I can't get it I'll probably try to use a plugin

Comment: when i insert that code it gives me a 500 internal server error. It looks like I have to study php before I can use this example, and go with a plugin instead. Which is a shame because I really like the custom background on this form. Maybe I can edit the css of another form from a plugin or something